# Not able to run Nodes on AWS Corda image VM

Tags: corda

I created a VM using Corda image which is available on AWS Marketplace. Now, I am trying run cordapp-example. I deployed nodes as explained at link https://docs.corda.net/aws-vm.html. Now, I am running command './kotlin-source/build/nodes/runnodes', but nodes are not getting started. It is throwing below error (just pasted only few lines). Am I missing any steps here?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-20-0-0-41: ip-20-0-0-41: Name or service not known

    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-20-0-0-41: Name or service not known

    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace please?

Comment: I could able to solve this error. I added my private IP address ip-20-0-0-41 to /etc/hosts file.

Comment: Thanks. Adding an answer below for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by adding the machine's private IP address (ip-20-0-0-41) to the `/etc/hosts` file.